# Standard Setting for Audit Policy in Local Group Policy Editor

Tags: windows, windows-7, eventviewer

Please let me know what is the standard Setting for below Security Setting ( Audit Policy ), which are followed in most of the Company.

For Eg:- Should i set ' Success & Failure ' for ' Audit account logon events ' & for ' Audit account management' etc...

[image]

Comment: There is no standard setting. Auditing is not configured by default. Any `standard` setting would be the setting that suits your auditing needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Security and Compliance manager baseline for suggested auditing settings for whatever versions of windows you have in the environment.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc677002.aspx